# Mercurial Tag rule engine

Tags: java, mercurial, tortoisehg, rule-engine

Is there a tag rule engine in Mercurial? I want to enforce the tag name. For example. tag VERSION 2.4...I want to have a way to enforce "VERSION" to be in the tag name no mater what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `pretag` hook on which you could add some validation. You have some information on this thread:
[Mercurial hook to set policy on tag names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746881/mercurial-hook-to-set-policy-on-tag-names)

­

> **.hg/hgrc**:
>
> pretag.badtagname = python:.hg/hgcheck.py:localbadtag
>
> **.hg/hgcheck.py**:
>
> ```
> goodtag_re = r'(ver-\d+\.\d+\.\d+|tip)$' def localbadtag(ui, repo,
>     hooktype, node, **kwargs):
>     assert(hooktype == 'pretag')
>     re_ = re.compile(goodtag_re)
>     if not re_.match(tag):
>         ui.warn('Invalid tag name "%s".\n' % tag)
>         ui.warn('Use one of tip, ver-xx.xx.xx\n')
>         return True
>     return False
> ```

You have some hook examples over here:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples

You can also consider enforcing these rules inside your release management process, ie provide build scripts where version is taken as input, validated, and **VERSION** is then prepended to the final tag name. It would not restrict people from tagging directly with an invalid name, but normally an automated release/build process saves so much time and error that no one wants to go back to a manual process.

Ideally this is all centralized on your CI server so you don't rely on custom hooks which needs to be installed in each Mercurial installation.